# python extract_msg module -env-3.7 - .tokenize_rtf - invalid Syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, email, syntax-error, msg

getting syntax error in okenizeRTF  python 3.7  . please advise

```
from .tokenize_rtf import tokenizeRTF
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\vvv\Miniconda3\envs\env-py37\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\_rtf\tokenize_rtf.py", line 68
    while (nextChar:= reader.read(1)) != b'' and nextChar.isalpha():
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

just 2 line

```
import extract_msg

msg=extract_msg.Message('testmessage.msg')
```

Comment: Please include the code and complete error message that you encountered.

Comment: did write much " import extract_msg

msg=extract_msg.Message('testmessage.msg')"

Comment: while (nextChar:= reader.read(1)) != b'' and nextChar.isalpha(): error saying python 3.7 dont accept this assignment.

Comment: works fine in 3.9 python.